# How to ping in linux until host is known?

Tags: linux, bash, ping, command-line-interface

How can I ping a certain address and when found, stop pinging.

I want to use it in a bash script, so when the host is starting up, the script keeps on pinging and from the moment the host is available, the script continues...

Comment: See also my `ping_loop.sh` script here: [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange: Equivalent of `ping -o` on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678191/114401)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

A further simplification of Martynas' answer:

```
until ping -c1 www.google.com >/dev/null 2>&1; do :; done
```

note that ping itself is used as the loop test; as soon as it succeeds, the loop ends.  The loop body is empty, with the null command "`:`" used to prevent a syntax error.

Update: I thought of a way to make Control-C exit the ping loop cleanly. This will run the loop in the background, trap the interrupt (Control-C) signal, and kill the background loop if it occurs:

```
ping_cancelled=false    # Keep track of whether the loop was cancelled, or succeeded
until ping -c1 "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1; do :; done &    # The "&" backgrounds it
trap "kill $!; ping_cancelled=true" SIGINT
wait $!          # Wait for the loop to exit, one way or another
trap - SIGINT    # Remove the trap, now we're done with it
echo "Done pinging, cancelled=$ping_cancelled"
```

It's a bit circuitous, but if you want the loop to be cancellable it should do the trick.

Comment: To add 'sleep' (e.g. each 5 secs): while ! ping -c1 www.google.com &>/dev/null; do sleep 5; done

Comment: By default `ping` will wait 10 seconds before giving up on its ping. If you want to reduce that to 1 second, you can use `-w1`.

Comment: @JackO'Connor Using BSD ping, this is a capital `-W1`

Comment: My only issue with this answer is it doesn't handle SIGINT well. You are unable to stop this from the command line, if it is never going to connect for whatever reason.

Comment: @LukeExton That's due to the ways bash and ping handle SIGINT, and how they interact (see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230421/unable-to-stop-a-bash-script-with-ctrlc)). I don't have a very good solution, but there's a kluge: use Control-Z to stop the script, then `kill %1` to kill it.

Comment: `&>/dev/null` caused the program to exit right away for me. Now I'm stuck with the output of `ping`, but oh well.

Comment: @JoshyRobot Apparently `&>` is a bashism, and has a very different meaning in some other shells. I've edited it to use `>/dev/null 2>&1`, which should work in all POSIX shells.

Comment: caveat that this is hiding the errors, so if you don't have the ping tool (this happened to me when trying to run this inside a container), or something else goes wrong, you won't know, and will be trapped in an infinite loop!

Comment: This is useful for testing when my broadband connection has gone down, which happens quite a lot in my area, and when it comes back up.

Answer (score 42):

I know the question is old... and specifically asks regarding `ping`, but I wanted to share my solution.

I use this when rebooting hosts to know when I can SSH back into them again. (Since `ping` will respond for several seconds before `sshd` is started.)

```
until nc -vzw 2 $host 22; do sleep 2; done
```

Comment: That's exactly what I searched for, thanks! You can even interrupt the call with CTRL+C which is not the case for some other solutions in this thread.

Comment: Note this works for BSD versions of netcat.  The nmap.org version in Linux distros is implemented differently, so the -z option doesn't exist, and the -w option waits for a connection but doesn't close when successful.  Works great in OSX, though.

Comment: This is why you don't stop at the first (fine) answer. This is the answer to the *real* problem.

Comment: Regarding whether this works on "Linux distros" or not, the default version of netcat in Ubuntu 18.04 is of the BSD variety and works exactly as described here.

Answer (score 30):

You can do a loop, send one ping and depending on the status break the loop, for example (bash):

```
while true; do ping -c1 www.google.com > /dev/null && break; done
```

Putting this somewhere in your script will block, until `www.google.com` is pingable.

Comment: This `while true` and `break` is the cleaner solution, IMO.

Comment: @DanCarley I'm going to disagree with you for the reason that in the accepted answer, the null command version, one could substitute a sleep/wait to give your CPU a break, and in which case I would call it the cleaner solution. The other problem with this answer, is that it requires the reader/user to understand how the && works, and how that if the first command fails, it won't be called. This is just an opinion, like your own.

Comment: The main difference I see between this solution and the accepted one, is that this one will echo the error message "unknown host ..." until its found.
To add **sleep** (e.g. each 5 secs): `while true; do sleep 5; ping ...`

Comment: this cannot be cancelled with ctrl+c

Answer (score 11):

Ping the target host once. Check if the ping succeeded (return value of ping is zero). If host is not alive, ping again.

The following code can be saved as a file and called with the hostname as argument, or stripped of the first and last line and used as function within an existing script (waitForHost hostname).

The code does not evaluate the cause for failure if the ping does not result in a response, thus looping forever if the host does not exist. My BSD manpage lists the meaning of each return value, while the linux one does not, so I guess this might not be portable, that's why I left it out.

```
#!/bin/bash

PING=`which ping`

function waitForHost
{
    if [ -n "$1" ]; 
    then
        waitForHost1 $1;
    else
        echo "waitForHost: Hostname argument expected"
    fi
}

function waitForHost1
{
    reachable=0;
    while [ $reachable -eq 0 ];
    do
    $PING -q -c 1 $1
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ];
    then
        reachable=1
    fi
    done
    sleep 5
}
waitForHost $1
```

Answer (score 9):

```
UNREACHEABLE=1;
while [ $UNREACHEABLE -ne "0" ]; 
   do ping -q -c 1 HOST &> /dev/null; UNREACHEABLE=$?; sleep 1;
done
```

You may remove sleep 1, it's only here to prevent any flooding problem in case where the host would be reacheable but ping would not exit with code 0.

Answer (score 4):

Please see good options at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733418/how-can-i-write-a-linux-bash-script-that-tells-me-which-computer-are-on-in-my-la/733453). Here is a sample in bash, you will have to loop over the following code until it returns a successfull ping result.

```
ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.1.1;
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "192.168.1.1 is up";
else 
    echo "ip is down";
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

any of the above loops can also be used with fping rather than ping which, IMO, is better suited for use in scripts than ping itself.  See [fping(1)](http://fping.org/fping.1.html) for details.

```sh
while ! fping -q $HOSTNAMES ; do :; done
```

also useful for testing if machines are up before doing something on them.  A simple example:

```
for h in HOST1 HOST2 HOST3 ; do
  if fping -q $h ; then
     echo -n "$h : "
     ssh $h "uname -a"
  fi
done
```

Comment: How do you kill the `while` loop!? Ctrl + C won't kill it, neither will Ctrl + D.

Comment: @GabrielStaples 1. the loop will terminate when fping returns with a 0 (success) exit code - from `man fping`: *"Exit status is 0 if all the hosts are reachable, 1 if some hosts were unreachable, 2 if any IP addresses were not found, 3 for invalid command line arguments, and 4 for a system call failure."*. 2. it's a minimum working example, not a complete solution. the purpose is to show the method. 3. do something other than the `:` empty statement in the loop.

Comment: cas, thanks. I added my own example here: [Equivalent of `ping -o` on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678191/114401). To enable Ctrl + C to work inside the while loop I discovered you can add this before the while loop: `trap 'printf "%s\n" "Ctr + C"; exit 2' SIGINT`. You can see that in my example too.

Answer (score 3):

For macOS users, `ping` has the option `-o` specifically for this:

```
-o      Exit successfully after receiving one reply packet.
```

So the command is simple:

```
ping -o www.google.com
```

It returns 0 when the host has been successfully pinged once.

Answer (score 1):

This will try a given number of times.

```
t=4; c=0; r=0; until ping -c 1 hostname.com >/dev/null 2>&1 || ((++c >= t)); do r=$?; done; echo $r
```

Instead of echoing `$r`, you can test it and act according to its value:

```
if ((r)); then echo 'Failed to contact host'; else echo 'Continuing with script'; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

In general I want to wait for my database or other server to come up, but I don't want to wait *too* long.  The following code waits for 10 seconds, then sets the exit code if the server did not appear within the time limit.

If the server appears before the time limit, the loop will be short-circuited so the next bit of code can run.

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do date ; sleep 1 ; ping -c1 ${HOST} &>/dev/null && break ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

To nicely handle the SIGINT on BSD ping.

```
HOST=google.com NO=1; while [ $NO -ne 0 ]; do ping -W1 -c1 $HOST &>/dev/null; NO=$?;echo "$(date) ($HOST) $NO" ; done; echo "$(date) ($HOST) reachable"
```

as a function

```
ping_until(){
  local NO=1
  while [ $NO -ne 0 ]; do
    ping -W1 -c1 $1 &>/dev/null; NO=$?
    # Optionally block ICMP flooding
    # sleep 1
    echo "$(date) ($1) ($NO)"
  done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Folks, yes this is old. A lot of good answers here.

But [I just found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024357/do-a-tail-f-until-matching-a-pattern) what I call a beauty! In case someone likes native `ping` counter:

`ping $HOST | sed "/ ms$/ q"`

Isn't this fascinating? :)

```
[p@localhost ~]$ VBoxManage startvm VGTU-2021-LDVM1 --type headless && \
> ping 192.168.10.14 | sed "/ ms$/ q"
Waiting for VM "VGTU-2021-LDVM1" to power on...
VM "VGTU-2021-LDVM1" has been successfully started.
PING 192.168.10.14 (192.168.10.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.10.8 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.8 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
  ...
From 192.168.10.8 icmp_seq=35 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.10.8 icmp_seq=36 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 192.168.10.14: icmp_seq=37 ttl=64 time=2003 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the following function.  I like it because I can tell it to stop trying after a while:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function networkup {
  # Initialize number of attempts
  reachable=$1
  while [ $reachable -ne 0 ]; do
    # Ping supplied host
    ping -q -c 1 -W 1 "$2" > /dev/null 2>&1
    # Check return code
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      # Success, we can exit with the right return code
      echo 0
      return
    fi
    # Network down, decrement counter and try again
    let reachable-=1
    # Sleep for one second
    sleep 1
  done
  # Network down, number of attempts exhausted, quiting
  echo 1
}
```

It can be used like this to launch something:

```
# Start-up a web browser, if network is up
if [ $(networkup 60 www.google.com) -eq 0 ]; then
  firefox &
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A further enhancement to Gordon Davisson's answer:

```
until $(ping -c1 www.google.com &>/dev/null); do :; done
```

with the surrounding '$()' a subshell is started and therefore you can use Control-C to terminate the loop in the event that the host does not become available.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat bin/check_host_up.sh
HOST=$1
PINGCMD="ping -c1 $HOST >/dev/null 2>&1"
while true; do
    eval $PINGCMD && sleep 1 && echo -n . ||    \
    (                                           \
        echo && echo "(${HOST}) down:" $(date) &&         \
            until eval $PINGCMD; do :; done &&  \
        echo "(${HOST}) up  :" $(date)
    );
done
```

Answer (score 0):

ping $HOSTNAME | grep from -m 1

Answer (score 0):

`grep` works on lines, so:

`ping google.com | grep "not"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't require cobbling together a shell script:

```
watch -n 1 -g -- ping -W 1 -c 1 192.0.2.1
```

Every second, `watch` will run `ping`, which will sent one ICMP echo request to `192.0.2.1`, giving up if it does not recieve a response within one second.

`watch` will exit when the output of that command changes, i.e., when the host becomes available.